# Simple Future vs Future Perfect

Tags: future-perfect, future-constructions

> *(1) I will finish the work in two hours.*

> *(2) I will have finished the work in two hours.*

There is a deadline of two hours. Are the two sentences correct and the same without any difference in meaning?

Comment: I see a slight difference: (1) says that the task will take (another) two hours to complete, (2) says that two hours from now I will certainly have finished it (maybe I will finish sooner).

Comment: Why (another) two hours? 'In two hours' means 'at the end of two hours' from the time of speaking.  It doesn't imply to finish sooner. But 'within two hours' may imply before the completion of two hours, i.e., before the deadline.

Comment: I added _another_ in brackets because it would be appropriate if the speaker had already spent some time on the task and estimated the amount of work still to do. Obviously you wouldn't use it if you were just starting a two-hour task.

Comment: @KateBunting, got it now. Thank you.